# why my android Koltin app crashes on opening in android 12 ( no errors on other os / emulator )?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a well working android app, developed in kotlin . i updated the target sdk to 31 in app level build.gradle file,

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.win.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
        aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
        compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    // For Kotlin users also import the Kotlin extensions library for Play In-App Review:
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx:23.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    // For Kotlin users, also add the Kotlin extensions library for Play In-App Review:

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.1.1')
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.0"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

it works on all versions of android execpt Android 12 and android 13 (but it runs on android 13 emulator). Please help me figure out and solve this issue
I'm using a depreciated method Network info ( as of sdk 31 it's depreciated  . Will that be the reason causing the crash on opening? but it still runs on a android 11 device and android 13 emulator.

i tried,

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1'
```

but it didn't work .

Comment: We can clearly see that you programmed it wrong isn't it?

Comment: Use Logcat to examine the stack trace associated with your crash: https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-debug-001.html

Comment: it runs smoothly on android 13 emulator

Comment: @blackapps what do u mean by, "programmed it wrong" ? i said that it runs smoothly on my android 11 device and android 13 emulator. the problem is with running in android 13 and android 12 physical devices( not emulator)

Comment: Start by checking the logcat. There will be a stack trace for the exception that caused the crash.

Comment: i am a newbie checking logs, so did u mean the red colored lines in logcat?

Comment: Deprecated method should not be a cause of crash, you can still use deprecated methods (even though you should phase them out from your app). Something has changed in SDK 31 and now you need to update your app to comply with changes. As already stated by others, you need to run your app in debug mode and check logcat to know, what is exactly the reason of crash.

Comment: @HaryHillary yes, red colored lines in logcat is a crash log. Add these logs here in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved it by updating the deprecated methods.

Answer (score 0):

Update this for Android 12 & 13

```
compileSdkVersion 33
targetSdkVersion 33
```